# Inverse Function Implied?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have the following transformation for the variables $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ into the pair of variables $u$ and $v$:

$$ r_1 =  \sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2} \\
r_2 = \sqrt{(2 \lambda - z_1)^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}\\
u = \frac{r_1-r_2}{2}\\
v = \frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$$

where $\lambda$ is a constant. Apparently, Mathematica is able to solve for the inverse function giving $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ except that it cannot solve for $z_3$. My question is: what is $z_3$ in terms of $u$ and $v$? Is it independent of $u$ and $v$? Does the Inverse Function Theorem tell anything about this situation?

Comment: You cannot get $3$ variables back from just $2$. The most you can do is calculate $z_1$ and $z_2^2+z_3^2$ in terms of $u,v$.

Comment: Yes I agree. The solution is $z_1$ in terms of $u$, $v$ and $z_2$ in terms of $u$, $v$ and $z_3$. Would it be correct to say that for fixed values of $u$ and $v$, $z_3$ can take any value?

Comment: In real numbers $z_3$ is limited by $z_3^2 \le r_1^2-z_1^2$.